# How are resources grouped into <ItemGroup>s in a .csproj file

Tags: c#, csproj

Looking at my `.csproj` file, the image resources are inside `<ItemGroup>` tags.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Resource Include="2b.png" />
  <Resource Include="Resources\foo1.png" />
  <Resource Include="Resources\foo2.png" />
  <Resource Include="Resources\foo3.png" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Resource Include="bar.png" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Resource Include="Image1.png" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Resource Include="cam.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Why are some of them in their own groups, while some share? Is it just an artifact of auto-generated XML or does it mean something?

Answer (score 0):

In a simple project file, you normally use a single `ItemGroup` element, but you can also use multiple `ItemGroup` elements. When multiple `ItemGroup` elements are used, items are combined into a single `ItemGroup`. For example, some items might be included by a separate `ItemGroup` element that's defined in an imported file.
[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/itemgroup-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022)